# How to save passwords produced by a for-loop in a file?

Tags: python

I have a code that generates characters. I want to make that my result from the for loop is saved in a file and all these results are separated using `"/"`.

```
# -*- coding:utf -8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python3

import random

chars = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
number = random.randint(4, 10)
length = random.randint(4, 18)

for n in range(number):
    password = ''
    for i in range(length):
        password += random.choice(chars)
        
with open('randomfile.txt', 'w') as writer:
    for line in password:
        writer.write(" ".join(line) + "/")
```

Result:

```
3/p/A/N/8/K/v/n/f/t/Z/L/5/Y/s/J/7/E/
```

It turns out that it divides one password by `"/"`, but I need to output the entire array and divide it. For example:

```
odcyUHFZ/n2s5gUvj/7SXRTy7D/Mw55R5kU/Afn7Pk7x/ZhHzqeWy/Vc5FSdck/a6oKWAiM
```

Comment: You can use the `grouper()` [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to divide the letters in `password` up into groups each `length` characters long. Then afterwards use `"/".join(groups)` to add the delimiter between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
password_list = ''

for n in range(number):
    password = ''
    for i in range(length):
        password += random.choice(chars)
    password_list += password + '/'

with open('randomfile.txt', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write(password_list)
```